# Insert file to Google Drive from .NET WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, google-drive-api

I have created a sample application to insert documents into Google drive in .NET.
I have used WCF service for this purpose. To the service method I pass: an access token, a refresh token, and an expiry time.

I create the authenticator and drive service with the Google drive .NET SDK in the service using the paramenters passed to it.
During insertion it gives the error

> You must provide a request body if you set `ContentLength>0` or `SendChunked==true`.  Do this by calling `[Begin]GetRequestStream` before `[Begin]GetResponse.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share with us the part of your code that does the insert? That could help us debug your issue. Also, you might be interested in our [.NET Drive sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet).

Comment: I have shared code on this link  ...
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2Xq62G1X2qlTnRsWWNsaFkySUk

Comment: I am using the same sample code as suggested by you.

Comment: Hi Alian it seems the .net drive sample has been developed using the old google client library which has some known issues. Can I get an updated sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a known issue with the library that has been recently fixed: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=181

If you don't want to update the whole library, just make sure you apply the patch at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/detail?r=fe2d32e0713ae1c6138af72049377b145d4fa6cf

If you can wait, a newer version of the library will be released soon and will contain that fix.

Comment: After updating the library with patch, I am not able to access the "Authenticator" class.

Comment: How should i use it now or what is the alternative for "Authenticator". Tried with OAuthAuthenticator and DelegateAuthenticator but got this error "Cannot implicitly convert type'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<DocumentsInsertionService.StoredStateClient>' to 'Google.Apis.Authentication.IAuthenticator'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

Comment: The Authenticator class has been removed in a recent update, now you have to use a class that implements the IAuthenticator interface, such as OAuth2Authenticator<TClient>.

Comment: Hi Claudio Can u plz give a sample implementation  for OAuth2Authenticator.